# Reference as key in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference

Suppose some data structure:

```
typedef struct {
    std::string s;
    int i;
} data;
```

If I use the field `data.s` as key when adding instances of `data` in a map of type `std::map<std::string&, data>`, do the string gets copied? Is it safe to erase an element of the map because the reference will become invalid?

Also do the answers to these questions also apply to an `unordered_map`?

**EDIT:**

This is my current solution... but adding iterator to the map is UGLY:

```
typedef struct {
    const std::string* s;
    int i;
} data;

std::map<std::string, data> map;
typedef std::map<std::string, data>::iterator iterator;

// add an element to the map
iterator add_element(const std::string& s) {
    std::pair<iterator, bool> p = states.insert(std::make_pair(s, data()));
    iterator i = p.first;
    if(p.second) {
        data& d = (*i).second;
        d.s = &(*i).first;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**C++11**

Since C++11 [reference wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) is part of standard.

```
#include <functional> 

std::map<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>, data>
```

**Using Boost**

You may want to take a look at [boost.ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/ref.html). It provides a wrapper that enables references to be used in STL-containers like this:

```
std::map<boost::reference_wrapper<std::string>, data>
```

Comment: but I can still change the referred object, which means I can change the keys dynamically, which is not allowed as it violates the stability of the order of elements within the map's underlying data structure RB tree or AVL tree?

Answer (score 12):

You can't store references in Standard Library containers - your map should look like:

```
map <string,data> mymap;
```

The map will manage both the key string and the struct instances, which will be copies,  for you. Both `map` and `unordered_map` work in the same way in this regard, as do all other Standard Library containers.

Note that in C++, you don't need typedefs to declare structs:

```
struct data {
    std::string s;
    int i;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to avoid having two copies of the string, should I rather use a reference in the `struct data` instead?

Comment: Also, when you say I can't store references, does you mean that the STL forces a copy?

Comment: @Helltone References are hard to use correctly as members of structs or classes - that's not really what they were intended for. Instead, you should use a pointer, or omit the string from the struct altogether.

Comment: @Helltone Yes, all Standard Library containers store copies.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the reference. The map can copy the content. This is I guess implementation dependent.

But tested with the microsoft STL.

```
struct data
{
            data(data const& rhs)
            {
               a new object will be created here
            }
            std::string s;
            int i; 
};
```

Add some objects to the map and you will run into the copy constructor.
This should invalidate your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a big performance gain if you choose pointer instead of object. Only do this if you're managing data with lot of existing string objects which need to hold inside the container. Also the destruction of the objects has to be managed manually before destructing the container.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question about `unordered_map`, `std::reference_wrapper` will not work in the case.

`std::reference_wrapper` is not a default constructible class. To create a hasher, `std::unordered_map` needs type of the key to be a default constructible, copy assignable, destructible, and swappable class. See the [std::hash](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

You could try write your own `reference_wrapper` which would be a default constructible class, and use your class as the key type for a `std::unordered_map` specialization. To check whether your class satisfy each criterion mentioned above, use related functions from the [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) library.