# Is it possible to use a member of a structure as a key in a map without creating a copy of key?

Tags: c++11

Consider the following structure:

```
struct MyClass{
    int x;
    double y;
    std::string key;
    MyClass (int const x_, double const y_, std::string const& key_) :
    x(x_), y(y_), key(key_){}   
};
```

This is my current approach to searching a map for a `MyClass` object:

```
std::map<std::string, MyClass> myMap;
MyClass tmp(1,2.0,"Some Key");
myMap.insert({tmp.key,tmp}); // I now have 2 copies of the Key in the map per object MyClass
auto itr = myMap.find("Some Key");
```

Is it possible to use the member in MyClass as the key without needing to copy the Key?

Comment: If you look at [this `find` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) you will see that it takes the key argument *by reference*. No copying of the key will happen. By the way, *why* are you wondering? What problems do you have? Are you doing *premature optimizations* (which is considered bad)?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `key` member from the struct then? Of course you will have 2 "copies" since a `pair` requires a key and the struct has a `key` member too.

Comment: I added Clafification to my question with a comment @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @RickAstley The struct must have the key member to make sense in context that do not involve using the object in a map

Comment: You can make the one in struct a reference instead .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference as key in std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235927/reference-as-key-in-stdmap)

Comment: References would be a way to not copy the string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235927/reference-as-key-in-stdmap for discussion on this.

Comment: @patatahooligan That won't work because after copying the reference will be invalidated.

Comment: @RickAstley I'm not claiming they would work, it is just a logical first solution to consider so it was a relevant discussion to link to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pointer to the string in the `map`:

```
struct MyClass{
    int x;
    double y;
    std::string* key;
    MyClass (int const x_, double const y_, std::string& key_) :
    x(x_), y(y_), key(&key_){}   
};

//... later
std::map<std::string, MyClass> myMap;
std::string key = "Some Key";
MyClass tmp(1, 2.0, key);
auto res = myMap.insert({key, tmp}); 

// now we have to re-assign the pointer to get the correct address of the map element..
if(res.second)
  res.first->second.key = &res.first->first;
auto itr = myMap.find("Some Key");
```

This adds unneeded brittleness though to save little space, don't start pre-optimizing if it's unneeded.

Comment: In my opinion it is never a good idea to store a pointer to an argument that has been given by reference. This makes it too easy to store pointers to temporary values. A parameter should be given as pointer if a copy of this pointer is stored internally.

Comment: @AndreasH. references can't bind to rvalues. This method is brittle already since the pointer can be invalidated by erasing the element from out of the map but keeping a copy of the `struct` around but there's no way around that without using smart pointers.

Comment: In Visual C++ 2017 (and older) you can bind rvalues to references (i.e. define `void print(std::string&a)` and call `print(std::string("abc"));`). This is non standard (at least gcc complains about) but the reason why I do not use references this way.

Comment: @AndreasH. Indeed, it's non-standard and thus it doesn't follow the C++ spec which means standard compliant code shouldn't care about it imo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a COW (copy-on-write) string in both your structure and your map key. But this could lead to unexpected behaviour as one could change the content of a map item's value without changing the key (which leads to itr.second.key != itr.first)

It's important that a map key is copied by-value because it must not be changed from any other than the map itself (the map could be - for example - a list sorted by the keys). So COW may be the only valid solution as it makes sure the map key stays the same even if the key-member of the structure changes.

IMHO you should remove the key from your structure and use something like std::pair. This way you can use it in a map without copying the key:

```
struct MyData {
    int x;
    double y;
};

typedef std::pair<std::string, MyData> MyClass;

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, MyData> myMap;

    MyClass tmp( "SomeKey", {1, 2.0 });
    myMap.insert(std::move(tmp)); 
    auto itr = myMap.find("SomeKey");

    MyClass value = *itr;

    std::cout << "key=" << value.first << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x=" << value.second.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y=" << value.second.y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```